# How can I get the value of a var whose value changes inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, function, variables

how can i get the value of a varible whose value changes inside a function for example my var total is changing it's value inside the for which it's inside the load: function but I want to use the result in the Series name

```
 var total = 0;
 $scope.chartMedida = {

    dataSource: { 
        load: function () {
            var def = $.Deferred();
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: ng.api + '/llantas/graficos/'+3}).success(function (data) {
                  def.resolve(data.data);
                  for(var i = 0; i<data.data.length; i++){
                     total = data.data[i].cantidad + total; 
                 }

            });
            return def.promise();
        }
    },
    palette: 'Soft',
    series: {
        argumentField: 'medida',
        valueField: 'cantidad',
        name:total.toString(),
        type: 'bar'

    },
    title: {
        text: 'Existencias por medida',
        fontSize:4

    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: true
    },
     label: {
        visible: true
    }


};
```

I'm getting the value of the total var inside the for but I can't display the value out of it , In this example I'm using it on name:total.toString(), pls help for the best answer

Comment: Set `series.total` **inside** the Ajax callback.

Comment: I guess Felix meant `series.name` but you should have understood what he meant

Comment: for(var i = 0; i<data.data.length; i++){
                        series.name = data.data[i].cantidad + total; 
                     } //LIKE THIS and  series: {
            argumentField: 'medida',
            valueField: 'cantidad',
            name:name,
            type: 'bar'

        }, //but nope it is not wotking

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$scope.chartMedida = {

    total:0,

    dataSource: { 
        load: function () {
            var def = $.Deferred();
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: ng.api + '/llantas/graficos/'+3}).success(function (data) {
                  def.resolve(data.data);
                  for(var i = 0; i<data.data.length; i++){
                     $scope.chartMedida.total  += data.data[i].cantidad; 
                 }

            });
            return def.promise();
        }
    },
```

...

```
    series: {
        argumentField: 'medida',
        valueField: 'cantidad',
        name:$scope.chartMedida.total.toString(),
        type: 'bar'

    },
```

Comment: Nope is not working " Cannot read property 'total' of undefined"

Comment: hmmm let me look a little deeper

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
series: function() {
    return {
        argumentField: 'medida',
        valueField: 'cantidad',
        name:total,
        type: 'bar'
    }
}
```

This worked for me on a test page, but I had to use dummy data...

```
console.log($scope.chartMedida.series());
```

I think the internal value is being set on init, and then does not change. This way it gets the value when it's asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.  Create a service and have the service set the value when the get data is returned.

I have made a [**sample Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OrZNTzBMMNJscNmqxtCR?p=info) to demonstrate the set up.  For the demo purpose, I have stubbed out the processing logic because my get data is just a string.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('myService', function($http) {
  this.dataSource = function(inObj) {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      //url: ng.api + '/llantas/graficos/' + 3
      url: 'myData.html'
    })
      .success(function(data) {
        var total = "";
        //for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        //  total = data.data[i].cantidad + total;
        //}
        total = data;
        inObj.chartMedida.series.name = total;
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
        alert("error" + data, status);
      });
    return "...waiting..."
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.chartMedida = {
    palette: 'Soft',
    series: {
      argumentField: 'medida',
      valueField: 'cantidad',
      name: myService.dataSource($scope),
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Existencias por medida',
      fontSize: 4
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true
    },
    label: {
      visible: true
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer if you don't want to create a service.

[PLUNKER Answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/KBcjqwaVb4cAbFvYgjwM?p=info)

This one sets up an iife inline function to do the same thing.  It just looks messier.  In fact, it would be much cleaner to set up a factory for chartMedida and take it out of the controller completely.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.chartMedida = {
    palette: 'Soft',
    series: {
      argumentField: 'medida',
      valueField: 'cantidad',
      name: function() {
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          //url: ng.api + '/llantas/graficos/' + 3
          url: 'myData.html'
        })
          .success(function(data) {
            var total = "";
            //for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            //  total = data.data[i].cantidad + total;
            //}
            total = data;
            $scope.chartMedida.series.name = total;
          })
          .error(function(data, status) {
            alert("error" + data, status);
          });
        return "...waiting...";
      }(),
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Existencias por medida',
      fontSize: 4
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: true
    },
    label: {
      visible: true
    }
  };
});
```